# How can I access div in a page from another page?

Tags: asp.net

I have a div in a script named: `firstpage.aspx` with an `onclick` button to go to `secondpage.aspx`.
From `secondpage.aspx` I want to access a div on `firstpage.aspx` and change it's inner html, inner text, and control.

Comment: You mean the firstpage is in an iframe? Or in another browser window? Why else would you want to change it?

Answer (score 0):

You can access PreviousPage if you have used `Server.Transfer`, not `Response.Redirect`. Here's how I would acess it:
In the first page set `runat="server"` for the div:

```
<div id="myDiv" runat="server">My First Div</div>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
```

And in the code behind:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Server.Transfer ("secondpage.aspx");

}
```

In the second page I am catching the div using `FindControl`:

```
 public partial class secondpage: System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            HtmlGenericControl myDiv = (HtmlGenericControl) Page.PreviousPage.FindControl("myDiv");
            Label1.Text = myDiv.InnerText;
        }
    }
```

You will find details in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6c3yckfw%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp)